# Gap between menu and submenu hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

I'm working on a horizontal menu with a submenu. I used jQuery on the menu to enable the dropdown functionality, which is working fine for now.

However, because of design reasons, there is a small gap between the horizontal menu and the vertical submenu. So when you hover your mouse over to the submenu, you're hovering out, which causes the submenu to dissapear, logically.

However I need that submenu to stay. Any ideas?

Check it out for yourself @ [removed url. solution provided already]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In css

change

```
#Menu ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}
```

to

```
#Menu ul ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding-top: 40px;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your simple solution

Comment: However, because of the padding, the parent li cant be clicked anymore?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the gap inbetween is a design choice use the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin so that the menu doesn't get told to disappear as soon as the mouse leaves the menus. Instead, there is a specified amount of leeway time where the user can leave the menu before it disappears.

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

You also have an animation queue issue. To prevent it use [this technique](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup).

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup

Answer (score 0):

you can add your gap in the css with margin or padding .

anyway this is a good link that you can make a menu :

[http://www.mycssmenu.com/visual_interface/template2/template.html](http://www.mycssmenu.com/visual_interface/template2/template.html#)